# How to test run plugins in screwturn wiki

Tags: c#, testing, plugins, screwturn

I am trying to create a plugin for Screwturn Wiki.  I have the test code running but I don't know how to start the plugins as well.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the plugin to a .dll, and then install the .dll plugin via the Wiki-admin panel.

The plugin can have a URL that points to the most recent version, and Screwturn can check this, but there are time-delays involved, and I've found it just easier to manually upgrade each time.

Comment: I hope we can come up with a better answer for this; I haven't worked on STW plugin dev since I commented on this. Am returning....

Comment: Which DLL should I install? The one named after the plugin? I'm trying to install the Active Directory plugin, but whenever I attempt to load the DLL through the admin panel it says "0 providers loaded". What am I doing wrong?